# heroku - I'd like to keep using iCloud Private Relay in Safari: how to login to CLI?

Tags: icloud, heroku-cli

I'd like to keep using iCloud Private Relay in Safari, my default web browser. It's an important Security Feature.

Any good suggestions how, then, to login to Heroku's CLI via OSX Terminal?

Comment: So far, it seem copy/pasting the URL from Safari to Firefox (no private relay), clicking login, then manually (don't have saved passwords in Firefox) logging in to Heroku, is the way that I do it. Heroku doesn't complain. At the same time could be smoother.